# Passing argument for delphi functions loaded through ctype module from a dynamic link libraries(char pointer, DWORD handle)

Tags: python, delphi, dll, ctypes

while trying to control an external device through USB COM with python, I encountered followings problem: The actual function, written in an DLL in Delphi and loaded into python using ctypes module look like this:

```
function DmxProOpen (cSerNo: pchar; var dHandle: DWORD): integer;
     stdcall; external 'DmxPro.dll';
```

This require  as argument a character pointer and a 32 bit int pointer. So in Python i wrote this:

```
SerNo = 'EN096445' #actual serial number
SerNo = ctypes.c_char_p
dLocalHandle = POINTER(c_uint32) #Local handle to pass onto the function
DLLIMPORT.DmxProOpen.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)]
DLLIMPORT.DmxProOpen(SerNo, dLocalHandle)
```

which generates following error:

```
argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Even though i see the type match that of the requirements. So the question is: how can I pass the Serial number which was given as 'EN096445' onto the function when it requires a 8 bit pointer? I have tried to explicitly make the SerNo variable a real pointer by using pointer() with a variable that stores the characters but that also generate the error:

```
SERNO = ctypes.pointer(SerNo)
TypeError: _type_ must have storage info
```

it also did not work with the method byref(). I also want to ask if there is a way to declare that the argument of a from DLL imported functions is by reference with the method argtypes from ctypes. I really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance and have a really nice day!

Comment: You can't know how to solve this until you know whether the Delphi dll is using ANSI or Unicode text. Depends on the Delphi version.

Comment: that I am not sure of myself. The DLL comes as a complete package and I have no control over it what so ever. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: As the vendor. Or inspect the C++ header file.

Comment: unfortunately there are no header file, just a small txt description file which i have already inspected and found nothing. I think I can try to ask the vendor but it is going to take a while, so are there any alternatives? But much much thank you anyway, you have been a great help

Comment: Read the ctypes documentation for a start. If it is c_char_p then pass a bytes object not a string, e.g. `b'EN096445'`. But if it is c_char_p then pass a string. At the moment you are passing neither. You are passing a type.

Comment: Exactly! That's what I tried to figure out on my own but couldn't find because I don't really know how to put it myself, so thanks a lot.